# Fine tuning similar_percent query which is timing out

Tags: php, similarity

I'm looking for a more efficient way to compare values.

Here's what I am doing. I parse logs and I store the values in the database, each value is about 500 characters. What it basically does is store the error in the log so when I read the next email I check if the error is the same as any previous one. If it is I group them together.

So everytime I come across a unique error it gets stored in the errors table.
Every new email that is read, I extract the 500 characters of the error, compare it to see if it is identical or close (usually 95%) and if it's the same error it stores the `email_id` and `error id` in a link table called `error_link`. I also store more details in the email table but thats not really relevant.

So lets say i have 5 emails

Email 1 is `error1`
Email 2 is `error2`
Email 3 is `error1`
Email 4 is `error3`
Email 5 is `error2`

On the first loop it would add `error 1` to the error table.

Email 1: In the error table I set `error_id=1`, `error_text="error1"`. In the `error_link` table I set `email_id=1`, `error_id=1`.

Email 2: In the error table I set `error_id=2`, `error_text="error2"`. In the `error_link` table I set `email_id=2`, `error_id=2`.

Email 3: In the error table I don't do anything as I found a match with `error_id=1`. In the `error_link` table I set `email_id=3`, `error_id=1`.

Email 4: In the error table I set `error_id=3`, `error_text="error3"`. In the `error_link` table I set `email_id=4`, `error_id=3`.

Email 5: In the error table I don't do anything as I found a match with `error_id=2`. In the `error_link` table I set `email_id=5`, `error_id=2`.

The code I use grabs the snippet from the current email of 500 characters, then loops through the errors table and run this script:

```
similar_text($snippet_new_pre, $snippet_text, $similar_percent);

if ($similar_percent > 95)
{
   echo "We have a match";
}
```

Now the problem is that the query is quite taxing especially as the query gets larger and I sometimes get `PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 20 seconds exceeded`.

I tried setting that to `0` and it helped but it sometimes gets stuck. What I am not sure is if this is happening because the time included in the whole script is exceeding that or if its the actual code below for 1 query.

```
similar_text($snippet_new_pre, $snippet_text, $similar_percent);
```

It does refer to that line, I am wondering if I just do the query more often when there is less emails will it fix it or do I need to improve the actual query itself and make that smarter?

If I have to make a better query other than reducing the size of the characters it compares any ideas, I was thinking run the query only on the first 100 characters, if it has > 60% then run the full 500 character query thus doing much less calculations on ones that aren't close to a match but not sure if this will help or not.

Comment: Although your extra information is helpfull, the problem will be inside the similar_text method. We need the code for that function to be able to help. The problem area's could be getting the 500char code or comparing the code to see if there is a match. We need those processes

Comment: @HugoDelsing, [`similar_text`](http://php.net/similar_text) is a built-in.  From TFM: **Note also that the complexity of this algorithm is O(N**3)**.  There's a deleted answer here that was pretty much on target...